# How to match lines with multiple regex-es at once?

Tags: ruby, arrays, regex, text, filter

I have an array which contains tags, usually simple english words, about 3-6 element. I have to select the lines from a text file which contains ALL the tags in any order (lower or upper case doesn't count, case insensitive). How can I achieve this in Ruby? Should I use regex-es or any different approach?

For example I know how to logical OR regex patterns /tag1|tag2|tag3/
Is it possible in any way to logical AND them? /tag1 & tag2 & tag3/ ?

Comment: [“And” in regular expressions `&&`](http://ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/and-in-regex/)

Comment: Don't forget to select the answer you found most helpful, assuming you were satisfied with at least one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way you could do it.

**Code**

```
def line_contains_tags(str, tags)
    str.scan(/(?:^|\s)(#{tags.join('|')})(?=\s|$)/)
       .flatten(1)
       .uniq.size == tags.size
end
```

**Examples**

```
tags = %w{tag1 tag2 tag3}
line_contains_tags("tag1 tag2 tag3", tags) #=> true
line_contains_tags("tag2 tag1 tag3", tags) #=> true
line_contains_tags("tag1 tag3"     , tags) #=> false
line_contains_tags("tag1 tag1 tag3", tags) #=> false
```

**Explanation**

The regex scans the string for each element of `tags` until it finds a match or concludes there is no match.  A match is the element of `tags` that is preceded by the beginning of the string or a whitespace character and is followed by a zero-length (postive lookahead) string consisting of a whitespace character or the end of the string.

```
tags = %w{tag1 tag2 tag3}
  #=> ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
regex = /(?:^|\s)(#{tags.join('|')})(?=\s|$)/
  #=> /(?:^|\s)(tag1|tag2|tag3)(?=\s|$)/

str = "tag1 tag2 tag3"
a = str.scan(regex)             #=> [["tag1"], ["tag2"], ["tag3"]]
b = a.flatten(1).uniq           #=> ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
b.size == 3                     #=> true
```

For the last example,

```
str = "tag1 tag1 tag3"
a = str.scan(r).flatten(1).uniq #=> ["tag1", "tag3"]
a.size == 3                     #=> false
```

Comment: Thx, followed your method I found a better way: if the array "t" holds the lines then
t.sort{|x,y| x.scan(/#{tags.join('|')}/i).uniq.length <=> y.scan(/#{tags.join('|')}/i).uniq.length}.last
gives that line that contains the most matches, and that is what I exactly want. Because sometimes only a subset of the tags defines well a single line from the text.

Comment: Even better:
t.sort_by{|x| [x.scan(/(?:^|\s|\_|\-)(#{tags.join('|')})(?=\s|$|\_|\-)/i).uniq.length,x]}

Comment: If you only need the line containing the most matches, consider using [Enumerable#max_by](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) (with your `sort_by` block), rather than sorting the entire array.  If you want all lines that have the maximum number of matches (in case of ties), you could follow `max_by` with [Enumerable#select](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-select).

Comment: Oh, thx, I have never heard of existence of max_by, ruby is a real treasure-pit.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. To AND the tags, use lookaheads after the beginning of string anchor `^`:

```
^(?=.*tag1)(?=.*tag2)(?=.*tag3).*
```

You can assemble this regex programmatically by looping through your array.

Comment: Thx, I don't understand this exactly. How can assemble the regex by looping the array? Maybe with Regex.union?

Comment: You said you have tags in an array, right? So you concatenate `^` then a series of `(?=.*` + `sometag` + `)`, which in the end give you your regex: `^(?=.*tag1)(?=.*tag2)(?=.*tag3)`

Comment: Nice one.  Konstantin, if `r` is xz's regex, `"tag1 tag2 tag3" =~ r #=> 0`, with `0` being `truey`, whereas `"tag1 tag1 tag3" =~ r => nil` (no match). xy, I don't understand what a return of `0` signifies in this example, as the first character of the string is part of a zero-width look-ahead.  Can you explain?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Good catch! I wrote the AND but forgot to match the line. Just added the `.*` at the end. Thanks.

Comment: I see that my puzzlement is unrelated to your answer, but maybe you or someone else could set me straight.  Consider: `"abc" =~ /b/ #=> 1`, `"abc" =~ /a/ #=> 0`, `"abc" =~ // #=> 0`.  I don't understand the last one.  Maybe it's a language compromise, because a truthy return is needed, but I would think it could be troublesome.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `#=> 1` Is that the match position? (Not familiar with that syntax)

Comment: Yes, I meant `#=>` to refer to the return value, which in this case is the offset for the beginning of the match.  (I believe `#=>` is written `#<=` in Oz and Kiwiland, which is probably why it was unfamiliar.  Ah, fond memories of two tours of NZ by motorcycle.)

Answer (score 1):

A non-regex approach is:

```
tags.all? {|tag| string.include? tag}
```

For case insensitivity, assume `string` is a downcased line. and tags are already downcased.

Regular expressions are more flexible; they can be configured to match on word boundaries, etc.

Comment: Mark, you could of course have a regex in the block to deal with word boundaries and case, e.g., `string =~ /(?:^|\s)tag(?:\s|$)/i`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Indeed.